Help with IP2368 for 20V PD Output – Not Working as Expected
I am using the IP2368 IC to achieve a 20V output for USB Power Delivery, following the guidelines in the datasheet. However, I am experiencing issues, and it’s not functioning as expected.
Here are the details:
I’ve carefully followed the datasheet specifications for connections and components.
My goal is to achieve a stable 20V output, but I am either not getting the correct voltage or facing instability.
Could anyone provide guidance on:
Potential troubleshooting steps for the IP2368 to achieve a stable 20V PD output.
Suggestions for alternative ICs that reliably support 20V USB Power Delivery output.
A schematic example that may help resolve my issues.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

What do you mean under "instability"?  You have provided exactly zero information about your setup. What kind of device do you use to negotiate the 20V power contract? Also, does your board do charging? What kind of cell configuration do you have? Which PD analyzer do you use to identify that PD exchange protocol is working and the link did negotiate the 20V contract?

Did you start with researching/evaluating the available reference modules with the IP2386 IC, widely available from EBay/Amazon/Aliexpress?

As I understand the datasheet of the IP2368, this IC is a charger and not designed to be used as power supply with a fixed DC output voltage.
It can enter constant voltage mode and hold the voltage as long as the load current is above a configurable threshold. But if the load current drops below that, the voltage is reduced as required in a charger in the final charging phase.
I don't see any chance to abuse this IC as regulated DC power supply.

It looks like the IP2368 supports Dual-Role-Power port using Power Delivery protocol, they mention the sink-source toggling over CC lines in their datasheet. It looks like when the connected partner is a power source (with all corresponding PD attributes), the IC will charge a 4-5-6S battery of Li-Ion (or other) cells. When the link advertises itself as power sink, the IC apparently will provide power (Voltage and max current) in accord with PD contract as a source.
